# Stack Exchange site for copyright help?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Does there exist a Stack Exchange site on which I can ask for help regarding whether I can use an audio clip? Basically, an SE for copyright law. This can be really confusing sometimes, and I don't want to accidentally steal from anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Not at the moment. If you look at the [list of all SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#), which includes sites that are in public beta, you will not find a site for copyright law.
(Note that [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/), although it deals with intellectual property law, is really a [special purpose site to fight abuse of the patent system](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/09/askpatents-com-a-stack-exchange-to-prevent-bad-patents/). Your question would be off-topic there).

Three are a few proposals on Area 51, [Law](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law) being the most viable.

In the end, however, advice given on SE will not guarantee that you won't get in trouble. Put bluntly, I doubt that "Your Honor, the guys at Stack Exchange said I could share that clip!" is going to be a good defense.

The safest thing is probably to get permission from the copyright holder, or pay a legal expert for advice.

Comment: I understand that. I just think that the SE community probably knows much more than I do about these things. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such a site. Site proposals can be done on Area 51. [This proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law) might be suitable for such questions once enough support has been gathered. [This proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66416/intellectual-property) might also be for such a thing.